# While Running My Phonegap Project its Give me console error,How to solve this error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, phonegap

While I am Setup my phonegap project and Running.Its Create a Console error with given URL i don't know whats its mean.While I am Setup my phonegap project and Running.Its Create a Console error with given URL i don't know whats its mean.While I am Setup my phonegap project and Running.Its Create a Console error with given URL i don't know whats its mean.

```
https://cr-input.mxpnl.net/data?_channel_id=&_partner_id=39571&_sub_id=0000&_app_version=1.0.23&_app=cs-dca
```

after cliking this link its give me Cannot GET /data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5P1n.png)

Comment: research "content security policy"

Comment: if Any Body any phonegap App With php codeigniter Webservices then please, share with me.